# How can I patch the inherited hook in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Just a simple example.

```
class Base
  def self.inherited(child)
    p 'Base.inherited'
  end
end

class User < Base
  p 'User'
end
```

This produces me

```
"Base.inherited"
"User"
```

This works fine but how can I patch the `inherited` hook of Base class?

Let's say I want my result to be

```
"Base.inherited"
"Something inherited"
"User"
```

and still have my User class inherit the Base.

Any ideas, workarounds?

Thanks!

---

Updating question to be more specific.

I need to run some code exactly at the time when class User inherits the Base without modifying User class.

Let's say I have Base class with it's defined `inherited` method. From one hand I don't know what other classes will inherit Base. From another hand I cannot modify the original `inherited` method of Base class.

So how can I patch that method?

Thanks!

Comment: from where *"Something inherited"* comes? give idea..

Comment: Eugene, if your question was answered you should check the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module Foo
  def self.included(child)
    p "Something inherited"
  end
end

class Base
  def self.inherited(child)
    p 'Base.inherited'
  end
end

class User < Base
    include Foo
    p 'User'
end

# >> "Base.inherited"
# >> "Something inherited"
# >> "User"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Alias chaining works fine in this case. For some reason I thought it works with common methods but not with ruby callbacks.

```
class Base
  def self.inherited(child)
    p 'Base.inherited'
  end
end

Base.class_eval do
  class << self
    alias_method :chained_inherited, :inherited

    def inherited(child)
      chained_inherited(child)
      p 'Inherited'
    end
  end
end

class User < Base
  p 'User'
end

# => "Base.inherited"
# => "Inherited"
# => "User"
```